# Axis2 : wsdl2java tool Command line

Tags: web-services

I have this WSDL File already given .
When i used the Axis2 tool wsdl2java -uri  StockQuoteService.wsdl

```
 <wsdl:definitions xmlns:axis2="http://quickstart.samples/"
    xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" 

xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
    xmlns:ns="http://quickstart.samples/xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://quickstart.samples/">
    <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://quickstart.samples/xsd">
    <xs:element name="getPrice">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="symbol" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="getPriceResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:double" />
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="getPriceMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="part1" element="ns:getPrice" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="getPriceResponseMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="part1" element="ns:getPriceResponse" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="StockQuoteServicePortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="getPrice">
    <wsdl:input message="axis2:getPriceMessage" />
    <wsdl:output message="axis2:getPriceResponseMessage" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="StockQuoteServiceSOAP11Binding" type="axis2:StockQuoteServicePortType">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"
    style="document" />
    <wsdl:operation name="getPrice">
    <soap:operation soapAction="urn:getPrice" style="document" />
    <wsdl:input>
    <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://quickstart.samples/" />
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://quickstart.samples/" />
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="StockQuoteService">
    <wsdl:port name="StockQuoteServiceSOAP11port" binding="axis2:StockQuoteServiceSOAP11Binding">
    <soap:address
    location="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/StockQuoteService" />
    </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
    </wsdl:definitions>
```

**What i was expecting is the java code that should be**

```
package samples.quickstart;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class StockQuoteService {
    private HashMap map = new HashMap();

    public double getPrice(String symbol) {
        Double price = (Double) map.get(symbol);
        if(price != null){
            return price.doubleValue();
        }
        return 42.00;
    }


}
```

**But when i ran wsdl2java -uri  StockQuoteService.wsdl**

i got this code of java files , where i was expecting the above java file

1.StockQuoteServiceCallbackHandler
2.StockQuoteServiceStub

**but not StockQuoteService.java**

package samples.quickstart;

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class StockQuoteService {
    private HashMap map = new HashMap();

    public double getPrice(String symbol) {
        Double price = (Double) map.get(symbol);
        if(price != null){
            return price.doubleValue();
        }
        return 42.00;
    }


}
```

please tell me why so ??

Answer (score 0):

wsdl2java command generates client code to invoke your axis2 service (i.e. Stub and callback handler classes). The business logic inside getPrice() method has nothing to do with your wsdl.

Comment: me also face the same issue, in stub class where do we find the actual operation in wsdl under porttype.